# wxWidgets drawing bitmap causing crash?

Tags: bitmap, crash, wxwidgets

I am trying to create a large bitmap with wxWidgets, drawing to that, and then overlaying to a GUI which is smaller than the bitmap. The code below works, but crashes if the bitmap size is 3 or more times the width & height of the GUI space.. This works out to around 4000x2000 px But I need it to be larger than that. The odd thing is that I tried essentially cropping the larger bitmap, and then drawing the smaller cropped version.. But it still crashes. Any ideas?

It crashes at  mdc->DrawBitmap(bmp, 0,0,true);

I get an error message: assert "Assert Failure" failed in wxBitmap::GetRawData(): incorrect bitmap type in wxBitmap::GetRawData()

```
  int bwidth = vp->pix_width * 3;
    int bheight = vp->pix_height * 3;
   wxBitmap tbmp(bwidth,bheight);
    tbmp.UseAlpha();

    wxMemoryDC memDC (tbmp);
    wxGCDC dc(memDC);
    //dc.SetBackground(*wxTRANSPARENT_BRUSH);
    dc.SetBackground(*wxWHITE_BRUSH);
    dc.Clear();

    dc.SetPen(wxPen(colour, 10));

//  if (chartScale < 1000000){

        GetCanvasPixLL(vp, &p2, maxlat, minlon);
        GetCanvasPixLL(vp, &boat, m_pfix.Lat, m_pfix.Lon);

        b1.x = boat.x + 50;
        b1.y = boat.y + 20;
        b2.x = boat.x - 50;
        b2.y = boat.y + 20;

        dc.DrawLine(b1, b2);
        memDC.SelectObject(wxNullBitmap);

        wxRect subSize(0, 0, (vp->pix_width)/1.5, (vp->pix_height)/1.5);

        const wxBitmap bmp = tbmp.GetSubBitmap(subSize);

        mdc->DrawBitmap(bmp, 0,0,true);
```

**UPDATE**

This is fixed... I noticed that I had not explicitly set the bit depth. When creating a bitmap below a certain size, it seems to produce a 32 bit depth image. Larger than a certain size and the bit depth drops to 24. This is when the crash would happen.

I explicitly set the bit depth to 32 bits by:

```
wxBitmap tbmp(bwidth,bheight, 32);
```

And haven't had any crashes. I don't know why this caused the crash though. If someone could enlighten me that would be appreciated!

Comment: did you run a debugger?

Comment: @user1489223, what is you wx version and OS/toolkit? Also, are you trying it in the scrolled window?